# Does not Orgchart JS work on smartphones?

Tags: orgchart

I tried using my smartphone, but I can not move the organizational chart screen.
Would it be any specific configuration to work well on browsers for smartphone or is it not possible?
Touch to move graph not work.

Comment: Next of OrgChart JS version will support zoom and pan on mobile

Comment: Download the latest version. Now OrgChart JS | BALKANGraph works on mobile

Comment: Cool, i will download and test.
thanks